# Paypal buy now button how to capture price/option dropdown data in ipn listener

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal pay now button with a dropdown where a user can select 2 different events.

How can i capture what was selected in the dropdown? My current form is not working.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TFMANJVCMFZX4">
<input type="hidden" name="option_name1" value="Dinner/Show">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/ipn">
<label>Dinner/Show</label>
<select name="os0" id="paypalDropdown">
    <option value="Meal + Event">Meal + Event $15.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Event Only">Event Only $10.00 USD</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input id="paypalButton" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

To be more specific, i'm using this library - https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn and i'm logging the variables and all the `option_name` and `option_selection` vars are blank

Answer (score 0):

onchange="myFunction(this)"

this is the entire object, an in JavaScript can be accessed like this

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    var dropDownValue = obj.value;
}
```

EDIT:
Oops, just read your code.
The select value can be accessed in PHP like this :)

```
    echo $_POST['os0']; // the select fields name
```

Comment: Updated my question with important info.

Answer (score 0):

if you have IPN, then PayPal will call the URL you have prepared for this moment and aftre the payment, paypal will send all the data you need. from address and currency to the name of the items he had bought and the price of them. so you can get them at that time.
otherwise you have to write a javascript which catches the selected value and send it via ajax to somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use hosted paypal button but have not defined any configuration in your profile.

You might be getting this error message : "PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website"

There is no need to capture the values in the form above as this is taken care by configuration on paypal account as below:

1. Login to your paypal account
2. Go to Profile-> Selling Preferences -> My Saved Buttons
3. Edit the sample button (Add a dropdown menu with prices and options e.g Meal + Event $15.00 USD, notify_url etc.)
4. Save changes
5. Select the auto generated form code which can be used without any changes

Comment: I am not getting that error message that you speak of. The transaction works just fine, but i do not receive the option_name and option_selection0 in my db log. The db log comes is part of the library that i posted in the question.

Comment: ok. that means your form is working fine. Have you verified IPN? You can look into history to check if it has something like:  option_name1=Dinner/Show 
option_selection1=Meal + Event. Also, are you using activerecords or doctrine. If doctrine, then implementation does not seem to support these fields

Comment: I'm just using the standard activerecord, not doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

To use the field **os0**,  you must also use the field **on0**

Where:

> **on0** = First option field name. If omitted, no variable is passed back to you.

.

-best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I actually was using the on0 field at one point and it still wasn't working.

Comment: so it means you are 2 steps back... now please add it and they we can try to solve the issue.

Comment: also, on IPN success, email the var_dump() data to yourself, you will know what is received and what is not.